# Eclipse Plugin Development Using Git Information

Tags: eclipse, git, plugins

I am currently part of a group who is in the process of designing our first Eclipse plugin.

Is it possible to integrate our plugin with a version control system such as Git?

For instance, a line of code should be highlighted in terms of when last it was changed (i.e., light colours for recently modified lines, darker colours less recently modified lines).

Is there a a way (via an API, an external git file, etc.) to get this information?

I am completely new to Eclipse plugin development, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this library [JGit](http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/10/28/an-introduction-to-the-jgit-sources/).

It allows Git integration into Eclipse. It grants access to Git, which in turn allows Git commands to be executed within an application (such as an Eclipse plugin).